# Post array of object to WCF Rest service using JSON?

Tags: iphone, json, wcf, rest

Need to send a complex object having nested IList from Iphone in JSON format to WCF REST service. The Complex Object is defined as following:

```
public class BatchData
{
   long BatchID;
   List<Account> Accounts;
   List<Contacts> Contacts;
}
```

Please let me know the Client side (IPhone) syntax to create the required JSON request and also the server side POST method implementation to handle such scenario ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the server side: define an operation contract which takes an array of that type. Search for examples on WCF Rest services (you'll need to use the `[WebInvoke]` attribute to define your operation) and you'll find how to do it.

For the client side: you can send the request using the [NSURLRequest class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html). And to create the appropriate JSON, you can look at the [NSJSONSerialization class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which will help you to convert between arrays (NSArray) and dictionaries (NSDictionary) and the JSON you need to send to the service.